# Bitcoin Lightning Network

Tags: bitcoind, lightning-network, balance, micropaymentchannels

I created a channel in lightning network, did the payment and the channel balance of the receiver got updated. But after closing the channel , the wallet balance of the receiver is not getting updated and the sender is also losing the funds. (Even after mining)

Is there anything that needs to be done for the balance to get updated.

Comment: Need more information to answer your question. Which software did you use? How did you close the channel (mutual or force)? Can you share the transaction ID of the funding transaction or the shortchannel ID of the channel?

Comment: I am running the lnd nodes in regtest mode. It is a mutual close using the lncli closechannel using funding transaction id command.